# How to detecting interrupt on a GPIO line in Embedded Linux?

Tags: c, linux, interrupt, gpio, pandaboard

There is an interrupt being generated at every 10ms on GPIO_39 in the [pandaboard OMAP4](http://www.ti.com/product/OMAP4460). I have registered a handler for this in Linux driver code, but the handler is not being called since the interrupt is not being detected.

I made sure at the hardware level (by probing the gpio pin) that the interrupt is actually being generated. It's only that the software is not being able to detect it.

I've the following in my driver code.

```
#define GPIO_NO     39

  iowrite16(0x3, gpio_39_address + 2); /* Configured the pin 22 to be used as gpio. */

  ret = gpio_request(GPIO_NO, "Claiming GPIO");
  if(ret < 0)
  {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "%s: Claiming GPIO_%d failed\n", __func__, GPIO_NO);
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: Claiming GPIO_%d successful\n", __func__, GPIO_NO);
  }

  ret = gpio_direction_input(GPIO_NO);  
  if(ret < 0)
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: Setting GPIO direction to input failed\n", __func__);
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: Direction of GPIO_%d set to input\n", __func__, GPIO_NO);
  }

  GPIO_IRQ = gpio_to_irq(GPIO_NO);

  if(GPIO_IRQ < 0)
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: Mapping GPIO_%d to IRQ failed\n", __func__, GPIO_NO);
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: Mapping GPIO_%d to IRQ_%d successful\n", __func__, GPIO_NO, GPIO_IRQ);
  }

  if((request_irq(GPIO_IRQ, ten_ms_int, IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING, DEVICE_NAME, NULL)))
  {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "%s: requeseting GPIO_IRQ %d failed\n", __func__, GPIO_IRQ);
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: requesting GPIO_IRQ %d successful\n", __func__, GPIO_IRQ);
  }

irqreturn_t ten_ms_int(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
  T_UINT32 l;
  /* Enable spi channel */
  l = ioread32(spi_base + SPI_CHCONF0);
  l |= SPI_CHCONF0_FORCE;
  iowrite32(l, (spi_base +  SPI_CHCONF0));

  l = ioread32(spi_base + SPI_CHCTRL0);
  l |= SPI_CHCTRL_EN;
  iowrite32(l, (spi_base + SPI_CHCTRL0));

  /* Enable dma channel 0 */
  l = ioread32(sdma_base + SDMA_CCR(CHANNEL0));
  l |= SDMA_CCR_ENABLE;
  iowrite32(l, sdma_base + SDMA_CCR(CHANNEL0));

  /* Enable dma channel 1 */
  l = ioread32(sdma_base + SDMA_CCR(CHANNEL1));
  l |= SDMA_CCR_ENABLE;
  iowrite32(l, sdma_base + SDMA_CCR(CHANNEL1));
  //printk(KERN_INFO "%s: 10ms interrupt detected %d\n", __func__, irq); /* I know that I've to remove this printk statement */
  return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

GPIO_39 belongs to the bank GPIO2 and the corresponding interrupt number is 32. But, the return value of `gpio_to_irq()` is 199. This is another cause of concern.

Please let me know if something is wrong in the code or if I have missed something.

Comment: Your code mostly looks OK. I think your first iowrite is probably at best unnecessary, what is it supposed to do? Have you checked your pin multiplex settings and verified that you can read the interrupt signal as a value (with the userspace interface, for example).

Comment: The first iowrite is the pin muxing part.

Comment: If you use the userspace interface can you read the external signal level correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the GPIO pin explicitly to detect falling edge.

At the gpio module level it is necessary to enable **FALLING_DETECT** of gpio.